Connections between FT (continuous) and DFT
Long story short, I'm trying to connect the DFT/FFT to the classical analog Fourier transform.  More precisely:
I'm teaching a mainly mathematical introduction to harmonic analysis (for 1st year doctoral math students with Lebesgue measure theory, but little to no functional analysis), but am also doing lots of applications.  I recently proved the Shannon Sampling Theorem, and will tell  students that the pipeline is that

you sample a bandlimited signal at the Nyquist frequency
you truncate this into a finite sequence, then compress/filter if needed
reconstruct $f$ via Shannon sampling theorem

Of course in 1) we never truly have a bandlimited signal, particularly if we're dealing with a time variable since $f$ and $\hat{f}$ both can't have compact support, and in reality due to errors and lack of decay of the sinc function, we sample a little more than the nyquist frequency (I'll mathematically prove why later, i.e. being able to replace sinc with any "appropriate" Schwarz function).
What I'm struggling to understand is particularly this:  if you digitally filter then how will this affect the frequencies in the analog reconstructed signal? Here I'm reconstructing via the classic expansion via sinc functions.
Another way of course to connect the DFT and FT is this: if say $\hat{f}(\omega)$ vanishes for $\omega \in [-1, 1]$ and we only look at time $t \geq 0$ then $$\hat{f}(\omega) =  \sum_{n = 0}^\infty f(n) e^{-2\pi i n \omega}$$
It is very reasonable then to approximate $\hat{f}(\omega)$ by samples $\{\hat{f}(k/N)\}_{k = 0}^{N-1}$ and to truncate the sum from $n = 1$ to $N$.  This precisely gives us the DFT, and if we want to compute quickly, as is reasonable to do, we use the FFT.
The question is whether this is what is $\textit{actually}$ done in real life (for say cell phone communication or other speech applications)?  I.E. if I tell students that the FFT as a fast implementation of the DFT is important because of this, will I be basically lying to my students?

Are you asking if we actually use the FFT to obtain finite sample approximations of a signal’s DTFT in real world applications? If so, yes. There’s tons of applications where we need to observe a signal’s spectrum, and finite sample estimates are all we’ve got.

"Are you asking if we actually use the FFT to obtain finite sample approximations of a signal’s DTFT in real world applications?"
I'm asking if we actually use the FFT to obtain sample approximations of a bandlimited (or what we approximate to be bandlimited) analog signal, not so much about the DTFT.
Though looking at the WIKI for DTFT, I guess what you are saying is really precisely what I'm saying?  It's just that for a bandlimited signal, the Fourier transform IS a sum as in my question's text.
Sorry, my specialty is pure math, and I'm very weak in my signal processing!

So, in sampling we obviously assume the signal is band-limited (I think you understand Nyquist). Because the signal is sampled the integral reduces to a summation over the discrete time instances. Truncating the sampled signal results in a uniform sampling of the DTFT, which is the DFT. We compute this efficiently via FFT. Does that make sense/answer your question?

The pipeline for what?

Is this question somehow similar to what you're asking?

"...Because the signal is sampled the integral reduces to a summation over the discrete time instances. Truncating the sampled signal results..."
Yes.  I mean this was never in doubt that this $\textit{can}$ be done, the question was whether it $\textit{is}$ done in practice, and this seems to answer that.
I still don't understand how AD --> digital filtering (via discrete convolution either with DTFT or DFT/FFT) --> DA effects the new analog's frequencies (FT) though.

"Pipeline" probably wasn't a good choice of words.  I just meant "what you do to an analog signal to store it, modify it, and reconstruct it" kind of like (very roughly) an MP3 or CD.

Sorry for the delayed response. While an anti-aliasing filter will be used prior to the ADC, those frequencies above $f_{s}/2$ will still somewhat present. The same thing will happen at the DAC output. Because the discrete spectrum is periodic, we use a reconstruction filter to remove these images. These frequencies above $f_{s}/2$ will then be there but suppressed by the two filters at the ADC and DAC. The frequencies below $f_{s}/2$ will be perfectly reconstructed.

I'm gonna try to answer the question as asked, but I'll put in an intermediate transform to be connected between the DFT and the continuous Fourier Transform.
The Discrete-Time Fourier Transform (DTFT) is essentially the continuous Fourier Transform of the sampled signal with the frequency argument normalized so that $-\pi < \omega < +\pi$.
Defining the Fourier Transform as
$$ X(f) \triangleq \mathscr{F}\Big\{ x(t) \Big\} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) \, e^{-i 2 \pi f t} \ \mathrm{d}t $$
$$ x(t) \triangleq \mathscr{F}^{-1}\Big\{ X(f) \Big\} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} X(f) \, e^{+i 2 \pi f t} \ \mathrm{d}f $$
And the sampling function as
$$\begin{align} 
\mathbf{Ш}_T(t) \ &\triangleq\  \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t - n T) \\
 &= \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} \tfrac{1}{T} \, e^{i 2 \pi m \frac{t}{T}}  \\
\end{align}$$
The sampling period is $T$, the sample rate is $\frac1T$, and the Nyquist frequency is $\frac{1}{2T}$.
The sampled continuous-time signal (still in continuous time) is
$$\begin{align}
x_\text{s}(t) &\triangleq x(t) \cdot \mathbf{Ш}_T(t) \\
 &= x(t) \cdot \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t - n T) \\
 &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) \ \delta(t - n T) \\
 &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x(nT) \ \delta(t - n T) \\
 &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] \ \delta(t - n T) \\
\end{align}$$
which shows how $x(t)$ is converted to samples $x[n] \triangleq x(nT)$ and this is also true:
$$\begin{align}
x_\text{s}(t) &\triangleq x(t) \cdot \mathbf{Ш}_T(t) \\
 &= x(t) \cdot \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} \tfrac1T e^{i 2 \pi m \frac{t}{T}} \\
 &= \tfrac1T \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) \ e^{i 2 \pi m \frac{t}{T}} \\
\end{align}$$
The resulting Fourier transform is
$$ X_\text{s}(f) = \tfrac1T \sum_{m=-\infty}^{+\infty} X\left(f - m\tfrac{1}{T} \right) $$
Clearly $X_\text{s}(f) = X_\text{s}(f- m\tfrac{1}{T})$ for all integer $m$ which is periodic in the frequency domain with period $\frac{1}{T}$.
Now if this is sampled sufficiently, then there is no overlapping any of these copies of the original spectrum $X(f)$ so we can look at only the original baseband spectrum, when $m=0$:
$$X_\text{s}(f) = \tfrac1T X(f) \qquad -\tfrac{1}{2T} < f < +\tfrac{1}{2T} $$
Now if that is scaled so that $f \triangleq \frac{\omega}{2 \pi T}$, then the DTFT is
$$ \hat{X}\left(e^{i\omega}\right) \triangleq X_\text{s}\left(\frac{\omega}{2 \pi T} \right) $$
So now
$$\begin{align}
 X_\text{s}(f) &\triangleq \mathscr{F}\Big\{ x_\text{s}(t) \Big\} \\
 &= \mathscr{F}\Big\{ \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] \ \delta(t - n T) \Big\} \\
 &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] \ \delta(t - n T) \, e^{-i 2 \pi f t} \ \mathrm{d}t \\
 &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}  \delta(t - n T) \, e^{-i 2 \pi f t} \ \mathrm{d}t \\
 &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] \ e^{-i 2 \pi f n T} \\
\end{align}$$
The DTFT is
$$ \hat{X}\left(e^{i\omega}\right) = X_\text{s}\left(\frac{\omega}{2 \pi T} \right) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} x[n] \ e^{-i \omega n } $$
Here is the relationship of the DTFT to the DFT.

Here are some point so ponder

The DFT/FFT is widely used in the real world and there are plenty of dedicated accelerators and libraries to make that cheap and efficient.
The main use is NOT to approximate the continuous FT, simply because the continuous FT is kind of useless. Integrating from $[-\infty, +\infty]$ is a problem we cannot look into the future and only a limited window in the past practical
The main use of the DFT is to get information about the the short term spectrum, i.e. its a good way to approximate the Short Term FT
The DFT can be used for filtering but in terms of LTI filters it can only implement FIR filters, not IIR filters. The FIR implementation requires overlap add, overlap safe or equivalent method
The DFT can be used to to time variant processing as well, but that's fairly tricky and requires complicated trade offs.


I still think it's good to think of the DFT as an approximation to the DTFT which is an approximation to the continuous Fourier Transform.  $$ $$  I also think it's a good idea to view the DFT exactly as the Discrete Fourier Series, which is what it is.  It maps one discrete sequence in one domain (say the "time domain") to another discrete sequency in the reciprocal domain (the "frequency domain") and the iDFT maps it back again,

I wouldn't say necessarily that the DFT is designed to extract information about the short-term spectrum. Rather, under the stationary assumption, we can assume that the $N$-length segment of the signal is representative of the infinite length signal, which makes the finite-length analysis meaningful as an approximation of the continuous spectrum.

Well, the continuous-time Fourier transform is exceedingly useful as a theoretical tool for designing systems.

@TimWescott: That's definitely true but the question was specifically about the "real world" which I interpreted as "can be implemented in a actual product or device".

@Baddioes: My point here is "the DFT gives your spectral information about a finite signal".  Of course you can extrapolate from there, but that depends on the application and underlying assumptions, not on the DFT itself.

I agree with what you were intending to say, I was just being nitpicky on terminology as short term spectrums don't really exist, only short term approximations of spectrums. So something like "to get information about the spectrum from a short term signal" or something like that.

Let's say we have a continuous time signal $f(t)$ which exists for all real values of $t$. We then sample the signal with period $T$. This means $f[n] = f(nT)$, so the sampled signal is only defined at discrete points $t=nT$. We can represent the sampled signal as
\begin{equation}
f_{s}(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f(nT)\delta(t-nT)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f[n]\delta(t-nT)
\end{equation}
The Fourier transform of $f(t)$ is
\begin{equation}
F(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt
\end{equation}
If we take the Fourier transform of the sampled signal, we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F_{s}(\omega) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{s}(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt \\ &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f[n]\delta(t-nT)(t)\right)e^{-j\omega t}dt
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Under the assumption $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left\lvert f[n]\right\rvert$ converges, we can say
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F_{s}(\omega) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f[n]\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(t-nT)e^{-j\omega t}dt \\ &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}f[n]e^{-j\omega nT}
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}
which is the DTFT.
If we truncate the infinite sum, we get
\begin{equation}
\hat{F}_{s}(\omega) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f[n]e^{-j\omega n}
\end{equation}
From here, it's obvious that if we let $\omega = \frac{2\pi k}{N}; k \in \left[0,N-1\right]$, we get the DFT, which is equivalent to evaluating the DTFT at uniformly spaced samples. An added bonus is that the basis for the DFT is still an orthobasis, just like the other FT variants.


Long story short, I'm trying to connect the DFT/FFT to the classical analog Fourier transform.

The classical treatment is "Digital Signal Processing" by Oppenheim & Shafer, ISBM 9780132146357.  As long as you're willing to admit the Dirac delta functional into a mathematics classroom, you can define a sampling process that causes the DFT to be trivially derived from the continuous-time Fourier transform.  It's a foundational part of signal processing; you don't want to ignore it.

...and in reality due to errors and lack of decay of the sinc function, we sample a little more than the Nyquist frequency...

In reality we often sample a lot lower than the Nyquist frequency, and when we do sample very closely to Nyquist we either intentionally discard fidelity, or (as in CD format) we need to use elaborate filtering to do it.
The Nyquist rate isn't a line that you toe up to -- it's a line that you generally want to be a good long way away from.

What I'm struggling to understand is particularly this: if you digitally filter then how will this affect the frequencies in the analog reconstructed signal? Here I'm reconstructing via the classic expansion via sinc functions.

This part is easy -- and should be easy to prove.
Let system $y = h_1(x, t)$ be nothing more than a cascade of anti-alias filtering, sampling at a sampling interval of $T_s$, and reconstruction.  With perfectly bandlimiting anti-alias and reconstruction, this should have a frequency response* of
$$
H_1(\omega) = \begin{cases}
1 & \left | \omega \right | < \omega_B \\
0 & \left | \omega \right | > \omega_B
\end{cases}
$$
Let system $y = h_d(x, n)$ be a filter in the sampled time domain, with frequency response $H(\omega_d)$ (note that $\omega_d$ is the frequency in radians per sample, and is not the same as $\omega$ in continuous time.  You can find the best way to deal with this pedagogically; but if you start throwing around naked $\omega$ everwhere, be sure to warn people).
Let system $y = h_2(x, t)$ be system $h_1$, but with filtering by $h_d$: a cascade of anti-alias filtering, sampling, filter $h_d$, and reconstruction, with all elements the same as $h_1$ except for the digital filter.
Then the frequency response of $h_2$ will just be the frequency response of $h_1$ multiplied by the frequency response of $h_d$ adjusted for the sampling rate.  In other words,
$$
H_2(\omega) = \begin{cases}
H_d(T_s \omega) & \left | \omega \right | < \omega_B \\
0 & \left | \omega \right | > \omega_B
\end{cases}
$$

* I'm apparently violating the rules of systems theory here, because you can't use a transfer function to represent a time-varying system, and $h_1$ is, internally, time-varying.  However, with perfect anti-aliasing and perfect reconstruction, the system is mathematically time invariant.
